# Showing a formatted elapsed time

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my upload file page I want to show an elapsed time (how long the user has been uploading the file for) in this format: `00:26`, which would be 26 seconds. `17:34` would be 17 minutes 34 seconds, etc.

How could I do this? I have an event that gets called when the upload starts so I can set a Date variable from there, and I also have a function that gets called periodically for me to update the elapsed time.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your current code? HTML and JQUERY.

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 4):

Manually: Off the top of my head.

```
var s = 0;
var startTime = new Date();
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    s++;
    var temps = s%60;
    var m = Math.floor(s/60);
    document.querySelector("#timebox").innerHTML = ""+m+":"+ (temps>9?"":"0") + temps;
},1000);
```

Then when it is done uploading... it would need to call

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

However I would recommend using something like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) though. Much more robust.

Answer (score 0):

client side I'm guessing.

Sure, setInterval() a counter function that starts on the 'click' of the upload. Your counter function could return to screen a kind of 'progress' - is this what you mean ?